# Arithmetic Sequence Word Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

. Lucy Ango’yuaq, from Baker Lake, 
Nunavut, is a prominent wall hanging 
artist. This wall hanging is called Geese 
and Ulus. It is 22 inches wide and 
27 inches long and was completed in 
27 days. Suppose on the first day she 
completed 48 square inches of the wall 
hanging, and in the subsequent days the 
sequence of cumulative areas completed by 
the end of each day produces an arithmetic 
sequence. How much of the wall hanging 
did Lucy complete on each subsequent 
day? Express your answer in square inches.

Answer (score 0):

length of painting =27 inches

breath of painting = 22 inches

This shows that wall hanging is in a rectangular shape which is apparent from the diagram as well.
Therefore area of hanging = length * breath = 27*22=594 sq inches.

Hanging completed on first day = 48 inches, 
since after first day she completed the Hanging in an arithmetic sequence on subsequent days.

Therefore area of painting left to complete after first day =594-48=546 sq inches,

Than also, days left= total days-first day = 27-1 =26 days.

So hanging completed by Lucy each day = total area of hanging reaming to complete÷days left

```
                                 = 546 ÷ 26 = 21 sq inches a day
```